# How to replace Sheridan 3D controls in VB6?

Tags: vb6, vb6-migration

I won the first price maintaining a big vb6 application that uses a large number of external controls
(big means: so big that rewriting it from scratch currently is not an option).

I'm looking for a smooth upgrade path to vb.net, replacing the 3rd party controls by more standard ones.

Is there an easy replacement for the Sheridian 3D controls? (I do not care about visual effects, functionality is the point.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's worth considering the commercial automatic migration tools [VB Upgrade Companion from Artinsoft](http://www.artinsoft.com/pr_vbcompanion.aspx) and [VB Migration Partner from Francesco Balena](http://www.vbmigration.com/).

They [both](http://www.artinsoft.com/3rd-party-library-extensibility.aspx) [support](http://www.vbmigration.com/documentation/chapter4.aspx) the Threed32.ocx SS controls. I *think* they both offer the choice of replacing with .Net equivalents.

Artinsoft are currently offering a [free version](http://www.artinsoft.com/artinsoft-renews-its-efforts-to-ease-the-transition-from-microsoft-visual-basic-6-to-microsoft-net-framework.aspx) of their product that can convert up to 10,000 lines of code.